# How do I position a background image in the middle of a container?

Tags: html, css

I would have assumed that this fiddle would result in the Lion's head being centered in the middle of the right div:

http://jsfiddle.net/v6dc7d17/

Why is this not happening? How do I accomplish this? I thought `background-position: center` should do this.

```
.full-half-image { 
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: remove the background-attachement

Comment: Well, it would seem it was that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have `background-attachment: fixed;` applied.

Background attachment fixed is relative to the viewport, not the container.

As far as I know, it is currently not possible to attach a fixed background relative to its container with pure CSS.